# Why is installing a 32bit package on a 64bit system warning about removing critical 64bit packages?

Tags: apt

When I try to install a 32bit library `apt-get install liblua5.2:i386` apt warns that is is going to uninstall a number of essential 64 bit packages. Some of them are being replaced with 32 bit versions but others will not be replaced.

Aren't 32bit and 64bit packages supposed to be able to work side by side? The system is Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and essential packages like kde-plasma-desktop, kde-workspace, build-essential, gcc-4.8 etc, are slated for removal.

Is that a fault in the design of the package and its dependents.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  build-essential cpp cpp-4.8 g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-multilib
  gcc-multilib kde-plasma-desktop kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin libbonobo2-0
  libbonoboui2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-perl libgnomeui-0
  libidl-common libidl0 liblua5.2-rrd-dev liblua5.2-rrd0 liborbit2 librrd4
  libtool php5-dev shutter x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xserver-utils
```

**The output in full:**

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-base:i386 lib32asan0 lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-4.8-dev
  lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0 libasan0 libatomic1 libc6-dev:i386
  libdbi1:i386 libgcc-4.8-dev libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0
  libreadline-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 librrd4:i386 libstdc++-4.8-dev
  libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386 libtinfo-dev:i386 libtsan0 libx32asan0
  libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-4.8-dev libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0
  linux-libc-dev linux-libc-dev:i386
Suggested packages:
  glibc-doc:i386 manpages-dev:i386 libstdc++-4.8-doc
Recommended packages:
  gcc:i386 c-compiler:i386 ttf-dejavu:i386 ttf-bitstream-vera:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED
  build-essential cpp cpp-4.8 g++ g++-4.8 gcc gcc-4.8 gcc-4.8-multilib
  gcc-multilib kde-plasma-desktop kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin libbonobo2-0
  libbonoboui2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-perl libgnomeui-0
  libidl-common libidl0 liblua5.2-rrd-dev liblua5.2-rrd0 liborbit2 librrd4
  libtool php5-dev shutter x11-apps x11-session-utils x11-xserver-utils
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libc6-dev:i386 libdbi1:i386 liblua5.2-0:i386 liblua5.2-0-dbg:i386
  liblua5.2-dev:i386 liblua5.2-rrd-dev:i386 liblua5.2-rrd0:i386
  libreadline-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 librrd4:i386 libtinfo-dev:i386
  linux-libc-dev:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gcc-4.8-base gcc-4.8-base:i386 lib32asan0 lib32atomic1 lib32gcc-4.8-dev
  lib32gomp1 lib32itm1 lib32quadmath0 libasan0 libatomic1 libgcc-4.8-dev
  libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 libquadmath0 libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++6
  libstdc++6:i386 libtsan0 libx32asan0 libx32atomic1 libx32gcc-4.8-dev
  libx32gomp1 libx32itm1 libx32quadmath0 linux-libc-dev
26 to upgrade, 12 to newly install, 30 to remove and 316 not to upgrade.
Need to get 12.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 73.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy liblua*` is interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `apt-get install liblua5.2-0:i386` instead; there is no `liblua5.2` package, so `apt-get install liblua5.2:i386` is trying to install `liblua5.2-dev:i386`, `liblua5.2-0-dbg:i386` and `liblua5.2-0:i386`. The `-dev` package is the one causing the removals.

The search extension happens because the package name given contains a `.`; from `apt-get`'s manual:

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of '.', '?' or '*' then it is assumed to be
>              a POSIX regular expression, and it is applied to all package names in the database. Any matches are then installed (or
>              removed). Note that matching is done by substring so 'lo.*' matches 'how-lo' and 'lowest'. If this is undesired, anchor
>              the regular expression with a '^' or '$' character, or create a more specific regular expression.

So you could avoid this by running

```
apt-get install ^liblua5.2:i386$
```

(which correctly fails). The rule is generalisable apparently; from what I've seen `apt-get` tries using the package name as a regex if it doesn't match a package name exactly, even if the expression doesn't contain `.`, `?` or `*`.

Comment: Is there an option to apt-get install that insists on exact match for the package name? Does the -0 have some significance?

Comment: See my updated answer. The `-0` is related to the library's soname (`liblua5.2.so.0`).