# Why does trying to installing a 64bit library via apt threaten to delete a number of required 32 bit ones?

Tags: apt, package-management, 64bit, 32bit

I am trying to run

`sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libpng12-dev libossp-uuid-dev libfreerdp-dev libpango1.0-dev libssh2-1-dev libssh-dev tomcat7 tomcat7-admin tomcat7-user` and when I do so I get the warning

`The following packages will be REMOVED:  libatk1.0-dev:i386 libcairo2-dev:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386 libglib2.0-dev:i386 libgtk2.0-dev:i386  libharfbuzz-dev:i386 libpango1.0-dev:i386 libpixman-1-dev:i386 libxft-dev:i386`

The packages there are used for 32bit development and I need them as well. Why does this happen. I though they are meant to be separate and independent especially as they are development libraries.

I asked a similar question earlier but I don't know if the answer to that one is related - [Why is installing a 32bit package on a 64bit system warning about removing critical 64bit packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212232/why-is-installing-a-32bit-package-on-a-64bit-system-warning-about-removing-criti)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far multiarch has focused on library co-installability, not so much development package co-installability; while it works for some packages, in most cases you end up in the situation you're encountering.

For cross-arch development, the recommended approach is to use a chroot, either manually with `debootstrap` and perhaps `schroot`, or using tools such as `sbuild` or `pbuilder`.

Comment: Isn't apt capable of handling that automatically? I thought it automatically knows how to distinguish 32bit from 64 bit packages as the programs dependent on the search for their architecture libraries in different directories.

Comment: No, it doesn't handle this automatically, it depends on information in the packages' `control` files (the `Multi-Arch` field). Some packages could be co-installable but don't have the appropriate declarations; in other cases it's a little more complicated.

Comment: Is this a bug? Shouldn't amd64 and i386 development both be possible on an amd64 machine?

Comment: @FaheemMitha it would be nice, but the multiarch spec doesn't require it so it's not a bug (a wishlist at most). Things are improving though, and with the addition of the [multiarch hinter](https://wiki.debian.org/MultiArch/Hints) they might get much better quite quickly.

Comment: @FaheemMitha the [MultiarchCross](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiarchCross) page has more details.