# How can an apt-get command be configured to ignore those it aims to remove?

Tags: apt, multiarch

Can the apt-get command be configured to ignore some of the packages it wants to remove. I run both 32 bit and 64 bit development packages as well as the programs created on them, meaning I need both the xxx:i386 and their 64 bit counterparts on the system.In this system for example I need to install a 64bit development package on all the related 32bit development packages are marked for removal.

```
root@ac02:/usr/src/packages/lazarus# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-freedesktop:i386 gir1.2-glib-2.0:i386 gir1.2-pango-1.0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo-script-interpreter2:i386 libexpat1-dev:i386 libgirepository-1.0-1:i386
  libharfbuzz-gobject0:i386 libharfbuzz-icu0:i386 libice-dev:i386 liblzo2-2:i386 libpcre3-dev:i386 libpcrecpp0:i386 libpng12-dev:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386 libsm-dev:i386
  libx11-dev:i386 libxau-dev:i386 libxcb-render0-dev:i386 libxcb-shm0-dev:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386 libxcursor-dev:i386 libxdamage-dev:i386 libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxext-dev:i386
  libxfixes-dev:i386 libxinerama-dev:i386 libxrandr-dev:i386 libxrender-dev:i386 zlib1g-dev:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev
Suggested packages:
  libcairo2-doc libglib2.0-doc libgtk2.0-doc libice-doc libpango1.0-doc libsm-doc libxcb-doc libxext-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0:i386 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 gir1.2-gtk-2.0:i386 libatk1.0-dev:i386 libcairo2-dev:i386 libfontconfig1-dev:i386 libfreetype6-dev:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev:i386
  libglib2.0-dev:i386 libgtk2.0-dev:i386 libharfbuzz-dev:i386 libpango1.0-dev:i386 libpixman-1-dev:i386 libxcomposite-dev:i386 libxft-dev:i386 libxi-dev:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gtk-2.0 libatk1.0-dev libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcairo2-dev libexpat1-dev libfontconfig1-dev libfreetype6-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev
  libglib2.0-dev libgtk2.0-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libice-dev libpango1.0-dev libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libx11-dev libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxft-dev libxi-dev
  libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev libxrender-dev
0 upgraded, 38 newly installed, 16 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 14.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 13.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

When a package is marked for removal, does that mean that apt-get thinks it conflicts with other packages? This I find rather unexpected as most development systems search for 32bit development packages separately form 64 bit packages.

Comment: Actually this is not about why the conflicts exist, it is more about the existence of an option to the `apt-get` or `dpkg` commands which will cause it to skip the removal of possible conflicts if the user thinks there are will be no actual conflicts. As I mentioned I don't think 32bit development packages will interfere with 64bit ones if the linker looks in different directories, unless some linkers are indifferent to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `apt-get` decides to remove a package as part of the installation of another package, it's because there's a declared conflict (which might not reflect an actual conflict). Non-multiarch packages conflict with the same package from another architecture; as explained in answer to [Why does trying to installing a 64bit library via apt threaten to delete a number of required 32 bit ones?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/343561/86440) this is often the case with development packages.

You can nevertheless force the installation of a conflicting package, using `dpkg --force-conflicts`. You'll need to download the affected packages and install them manually, and you won't be able to use `apt-get` until the conflict is resolved (or rather, `apt-get` will insist on resolving the conflict). You might break the packages involved in the conflict, but at least you can try...

I'm not aware of an option to disable `apt-get`'s conflict handling.

An alternative is to fix the affected packages; this is simple enough in most cases and will avoid any subsequent issues with `apt`. For example, for `harfbuzz` in Debian 8:

- download the source code and extract it:

  ```
  dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/h/harfbuzz/harfbuzz_0.9.35-2.dsc
  cd harfbuzz-0.9.35
  ```
- edit `debian/control` and add `Multi-Arch: same` after the `Architecture` line under `Package: libharfbuzz-dev`
- add a changelog entry so that your custom packages won't be replaced by the current version from the archive:

  ```
  dch -n "Enable Multi-Arch on the -dev package."
  ```
- build the package (you'll need to do this on an `amd64` builder and an `i386` builder — this is where `pbuilder` or `sbuild` come in handy)

  ```
  dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
  ```

This will produce co-installable `libharfbuzz-dev` packages. It works because the packages already were co-installable, they just lacked the necessary meta-data. For `harfbuzz` this has been fixed in Debian 9.