# What is the difference between these apt-commands to install libglib2.0:i386 and libglib2.0-0:i386?

Tags: apt, multiarch

I need get a 32bit program working on a 64bit system and I have managed to install the required libraries to a certain stage. There is a a dependency on libglib-2.0.so. I am using 2 different options to try to install it. With the first option broken packages are blamed in the second option, the command aims to remove most of the 64bit libraries from the system.

This first block shows the missing dependencies. The second block shows the results of executing `apt-get install libglib2.0:i386` and the third one the result of executing `apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386`. The last one may be related to this question - [Why is installing a 32bit package on a 64bit system warning about removing critical 64bit packages?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212232/why-is-installing-a-32bit-package-on-a-64bit-system-warning-about-removing-criti)

It seems that adding `-0` to `libglib2` makes a lot of difference. Why should the `libglib2.0-0:i386` result in the removal of nearly all the 64bit packages?

**ldd fpcupdeluxe-i386-linux**

```
vfclists@hp03:~/Programs/Lazarus/FPCUpExes/fpcupdeluxe_i386$ ldd fpcupdeluxe-i386-linux
        linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77f0000)                                                                                                                                        
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2 (0xf77cd000)                                                                                                 
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0 (0xf77b1000)                                                                                       
        libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found                                                                                                                                    
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf765e000)                                                                                                     
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => not found                                                                                                                                 
        libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => not found                                                                                                                                    
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
        libgthread-2.0.so.0 => not found
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => not found
        libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
        libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0xf7514000)
        libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xf7366000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56630000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7340000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf7287000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf7244000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf7191000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf7164000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf7160000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf7155000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0xf7149000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7133000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7116000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1 (0xf710d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libm.so.6 (0xf70c7000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf70c3000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf70bc000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf7093000)
vfclists@hp03:~/Programs/Lazarus/FPCUpExes/fpcupdeluxe_i386$
```

**apt-get install libglib2.0:i386**

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                 
Building dependency tree                                                                                      
Reading state information... Done                                                                             
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-refdbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                             
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                  
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                    
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dev:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                  
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                 
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                  
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                  
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0-dbg:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-bin:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                  
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-cil-dev:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                              
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-tests:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'                                                
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-data' instead of 'libglib2.0-data:i386'                                           
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-doc' instead of 'libglib2.0-doc:i386'                                             
libglib2.0-data is already the newest version.                                                                
libglib2.0-data set to manually installed.                                                                    
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have                                             
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable                                            
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created                                            
or been moved out of Incoming.                                                                                
The following information may help to resolve the situation:                                                  

The following packages have unmet dependencies:                                                               
 libglib2.0-cil:i386 : Depends: cli-common:i386 (>= 0.5.6) but it is not installable                          
                       Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil:i386 (>= 3.2.8) but it is not installable               
                       Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil:i386 (>= 3.2.8) but it is not installable               
 libglib2.0-dev:i386 : Depends: libpcre3-dev:i386 (>= 1:8.31) but it is not going to be installed             
                       Depends: zlib1g-dev:i386 but it is not going to be installed                           
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.                                                 
root@hp03:~/workpad/packages#
```

**apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386**

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  crda freeglut3 iw javascript-common kde-base-artwork kde-wallpapers
  kde-wallpapers-default kde-workspace-data libavcodec57 libavutil55
  libcairo-script-interpreter2 libcln6 libepub0 libexpat1-dev libfreetype6-dev
  libice-dev libjs-jquery liblz4-1 liblzo2-2 libnl-genl-3-200 libopenjp2-7
  libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libpixman-1-dev libpng12-dev libpoppler46
  libpthread-stubs0-dev libqalculate5-data libsm-dev libsmokebase3 libsnappy1
  libsoxr0 libssh-4 libswresample2 libswscale4 libvpx4 libwavpack1 libx11-dev
  libx11-doc libx265-87 libxau-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-shm0-dev
  libxcb1-dev libxcomposite-dev libxcursor-dev libxdamage-dev libxdmcp-dev
  libxext-dev libxfixes-dev libxi-dev libxinerama-dev libxrandr-dev
  libxrender-dev libzip2 mc-data nxproxy oxygencursors poppler-data
  python-dbus-dev python-gdbm python-lz4 python-lzo python-netifaces
  python-opengl python-rencode python-sip python-wicd python3-apt
  python3-software-properties rfkill ruby ruby2.1 rubygems-integration
  unattended-upgrades unzip wireless-regdb wpasupplicant
  x11proto-composite-dev x11proto-core-dev x11proto-damage-dev
  x11proto-fixes-dev x11proto-input-dev x11proto-kb-dev x11proto-randr-dev
  x11proto-render-dev x11proto-xext-dev x11proto-xinerama-dev xorg
  xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libffi6:i386 libpcre3:i386 libselinux1:i386 pinentry-curses
Suggested packages:
  pinentry-doc
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  adwaita-icon-theme akonadi-backend-mysql akonadi-server at-spi2-core colord
  dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service debhelper desktop-base dh-autoreconf
  dh-strip-nondeterminism dolphin enchant firefox freespacenotifier gettext
  gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gtk-2.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-services
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-plugins-base intltool-debian
  irqbalance kate katepart kde-runtime kde-style-oxygen kde-window-manager
  kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kdelibs-bin
  kdelibs5-plugins kdepim-runtime kdepimlibs-kio-plugins kdm kdoctools
  kinfocenter klipper kmenuedit konsole kscreen ksysguard libakonadi-calendar4
  libakonadi-contact4 libakonadi-kcal4 libakonadi-kde4 libakonadi-kmime4
  libakonadi-notes4 libakonadiprotocolinternals1 libass5 libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-dev libatspi2.0-0 libattica0.4 libbaloocore4
  libbaloofiles4 libbalooqueryparser4 libbaloowidgets4 libbalooxapian4
  libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2-dev libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcroco3
  libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf1 libenchant1c2a
  libfile-mimeinfo-perl libfontconfig1-dev libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev libgirepository-1.0-1 libglade2-0 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk2.0-0
  libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-dev libgtkglext1 libgudev-1.0-0 libgusb2
  libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b
  libjson-glib-1.0-0 libkabc4 libkactivities-bin libkactivities-models1
  libkactivities6 libkalarmcal2 libkateinterfaces4 libkatepartinterfaces4
  libkcal4 libkcalcore4 libkcalutils4 libkcmutils4 libkde3support4
  libkdeclarative5 libkdecorations4abi2 libkdecore5 libkdesu5 libkdeui5
  libkdewebkit5 libkdnssd4 libkemoticons4 libkephal4abi1 libkfile4
  libkfilemetadata4 libkgapi2-2 libkholidays4 libkhtml5 libkidletime4
  libkimap4 libkio5 libkjsapi4 libkjsembed4 libkldap4 libkmbox4
  libkmediaplayer4 libkmime4 libknewstuff2-4 libknewstuff3-4 libknotifyconfig4
  libkntlm4 libkolab0 libkonq-common libkonq5abi1 libkparts4
  libkpimidentities4 libkpimtextedit4 libkpimutils4 libkprintutils4 libkpty4
  libkresources4 libkrosscore4 libkscreen1 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4
  libksignalplotter4 libktexteditor4 libkunitconversion4 libkutils4
  libkwineffects1abi5 libkwinglesutils1 libkwinglutils1abi2 libkworkspace4abi2
  libkxmlrpcclient4 libmailtransport4 libmicroblog4 libnepomuk4
  libnepomukcore4 libnepomukquery4a libnepomukutils4 libnotify4
  libntrack-qt4-1 libpango-1.0-0 libpango1.0-0 libpango1.0-dev
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0 libpangoxft-1.0-0
  libphonon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasma3 libplasmaclock4abi4
  libplasmagenericshell4 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpolkit-qt-1-1 libpoppler-qt4-4 libprison0
  libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libqalculate5
  libqca2 libqimageblitz4 libqjson0 libqmobipocket1 libqt4-dbus
  libqt4-declarative libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl
  libqt4-qt3support libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql
  libqt4-sql-mysql libqt4-svg libqt4-test libqt4-xml libqt4-xmlpatterns
  libqtassistantclient4 libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libqtgui4 libqtruby4shared2
  libqtwebkit4 librest-0.7-0 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsecret-1-0
  libsmokekdecore4-3 libsmokekdeui4-3 libsmokekfile3 libsmokekhtml3
  libsmokekio3 libsmokeknewstuff2-3 libsmokeknewstuff3-3 libsmokekparts3
  libsmokektexteditor3 libsmokekutils3 libsmokeplasma3 libsmokeqtcore4-3
  libsmokeqtdbus4-3 libsmokeqtgui4-3 libsmokeqtnetwork4-3 libsmokeqtopengl4-3
  libsmokeqtsql4-3 libsmokeqtsvg4-3 libsmokeqtwebkit4-3 libsmokeqtxml4-3
  libsmokesolid3 libsolid4 libsoprano4 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1
  libsyndication4 libtaskmanager4abi4 libthreadweaver4 libudisks2-0
  libupower-glib3 libweather-ion6 libxft-dev mc phonon phonon-backend-vlc
  pinentry-gtk2 pkg-config plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop
  plasma-scriptengine-javascript plasma-scriptengine-python
  plasma-scriptengine-ruby plasma-scriptengine-superkaramba
  plasma-scriptengine-webkit plasma-scriptengines plasma-widgets-workspace
  po-debconf policykit-1 polkit-kde-1 python-avahi python-dbus python-gi
  python-gi-cairo python-glade2 python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gtk2
  python-gtkglext1 python-kde4 python-qt4 python-qt4-dbus python3-dbus
  python3-gi qdbus ruby-kde4 ruby-plasma ruby-qt4 ruby-qt4-webkit
  shared-mime-info software-properties-common soprano-daemon sshfs
  systemsettings task-desktop udisks2 upower virtualbox-qt vlc vlc-nox
  vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vlc-plugin-samba wicd-daemon wicd-gtk
  x2goclient xpra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libffi6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libpcre3:i386 libselinux1:i386
  pinentry-curses
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 307 to remove and 26 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Your related question explains the `libglib2.0` behaviour, not the `libglib2.0-0` behaviour — the former doesn't exist as a package, so it's taken as a regex and causes `apt-get` to attempt to install all the packages whose names contain `libglib2.0` (it lists them all, saying "Note, selecting ..."). Regarding `libglib2.0-0:i386`, are you sure you're running `apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386` only? There's something else going on because `apt-get` is attempting to install `pinentry-curses`. What does `apt-get -f install` say?

Comment: `apt-get -f install` doesn't have anything to install.

With regards to the output line from the `ldd` - `Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-0:i386' for regex 'libglib2.0'` would `libglib2.0-bin:i386` be a likely candidate, as it seems to be a binary?

Is `libglib2.0-0:i386` from the `ldd` command likely to be referring to the `glibc` library?

Comment: No, `libglib2.0-0:i386` is the correct package. You can use `apt-file` to identify packages containing specific files.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question; I'd like to figure out why `pinentry-curses` is popping up there (as well as figure out why `apt-get` wants to remlove all those packages of course).

Comment: According to the debian site `pinentry-curses`is a package designed to stop passwords or pins from being stored in memory.  https://packages.debian.org/jessie/pinentry-curses

Comment: I know what the package does, the issue is that there's something you're doing that's causing `apt-get` to want to install it. Just running `apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386` shouldn't involve installing `pinentry-curses` at all.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea why pinentry-curses is being installed, but why should  `libglib2.0-0:i386` require so many packages to be removed on a 64bit system?

Comment: It shouldn't, which is why I think there's something else going on. (I have `libglib2.0-0:i386` and `libglib2.0-0:amd64` installed on several systems without issue.)